# Undefined filter parameter in Hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to map a LocalDate to a SQL Date, but am receiving this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Undefined filter parameter
> [afterDateLocal]

I can't provide a reproducible example, but here's the code of the ListingRepositoryImpl:

```
    if (!queries.get("checkInDate").get(0).equals("undefined")) {
        Filter afterDateFilter = session.enableFilter("afterDateFilter");

        String afterDate = queries.get("checkInDate").get(0);
        LocalDate afterDateLocal = LocalDate.parse(afterDate);

        System.out.println("After date: " + afterDateLocal);
        afterDateFilter.setParameter("afterDateLocal", afterDateLocal);
    } else {
        session.disableFilter("afterDateFilter");
    }
```

And the filters defined on the entity listing:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="listing")
@FilterDefs({
        @FilterDef(name="priceFilter", parameters=@ParamDef(name="priceComparison",type="double")),
        @FilterDef(name="beforeDateFilter", parameters=@ParamDef(name="beforeDateLocal", type="date")),
        @FilterDef(name="afterDateFilter", parameters=@ParamDef(name="afterDateLocal", type="date"))
})
@Filters({
        @Filter(name="priceFilter", condition="price <= :priceComparison"),
        @Filter(name="beforeDateFilter", condition=":beforeDateLocal <= date"),
        @Filter(name="afterDateFilter", condition=":afterDateLocal >= date")
})
```

I am using Hibernate 5.5.7 so I expect LocalDate to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`date` was not defined in the database, which is why I received the error.

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem ("Undefined filter parameter date value") with creating a filter with the LocalDate and i tried this at the type attribute (type = "java.time.LocalDate") and it worked for me.